# Wrong packages version in RPM database

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, rpm

While doing an update of some SAS packages on redhat 7, it failed and i restore the directory where it was supposed to be installed (/opt/sas).

However i had no backup of /var/lib/ and hence I now have newer package versions listed in rpm databases than those actually installed.

One key issue now, is that i cannot replay the update since packages are already up-to-date from rpm database point of view.

I do have a listing of all the packages version that were supposed to be updated prior to the update.

Can I somehow reflect the current situation in rpm databases?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Two options here:

**You want to update files in /var/lib from currently installed packages**: Run `yum reinstall $(rpm -qa --qf '%{name} ')`

**You want to downgrade the packages to previous versions**: play with 'yum downgrade NAMEOFPACKAGES` but that is not guaranteed that you get the exact version as previously. No real experience with this one.